# Processing app links like the YouTube app does

Tags: android

Just as the YouTube app intercepts URLs to youtube.com, mine does the same for my site.  I'm trying to implement behavior like the YouTube app, namely:

1. If the home button is pressed and the app's icon is clicked, the app simply resumes where it was (standard behavior).
2. If you start the app from the launcher and navigate to some activity (say the settings activity), then go to another app and click a youtube link, then the app tears down the activity stack to the main activity, then plays the video.

It's surprisingly difficult to get both.  I've been scouring [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) and blogs to no avail.  I did get **very close** by handling data Uris via an alternate activity instead of the main activity, like this:

```
public class AppLinkActivity extends MainActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent());
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

The only flaw was that if **initially** launched via a Uri, then clicking the home button and then clicking the launcher icon always went to the main activity rather than whatever was current.

This seems like it should be a common pattern so it shouldn't be that difficult.  Any hints?

[Edit] I have `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the manifest for the  AppLinkActivity.  The MainActivity has no special flags.

Comment: what you are doing is called *deep-linking*. It is indeed a complex matter, and several libraries can help you, including I think one from AirBnB

Comment: It has something in common with [deep linking](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) but that's more about making your app searchable.  I'm not doing that. I'm just responding to certain links when the user clicks on them.  And that part is working fine.  I'm just talking about navigation.

Comment: deep-linking is just the fact of having specific urls to point to specific places in your app. It is necessary for app indexing, but you don't have to go all the way in app indexing to handle your website's url in your deep-linked app.

Comment: regarding navigation, I am not sure why the main activity is restarted instead of the previously shown one, but it could be because that activity now belongs to the task it was started from. Possibly a NEW_TASK flag could help that, or a more specific definition of task affinity

Comment: Edited to add comment about android:launchMode="singleTask".  Without it, activities stack up like A-B-C-A-B-C etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  I found a way to accomplish this.  If anyone knows a more elegant way, please comment.

I got rid of AppLinkActivity and just used MainActivity, which has no special flags in the manifest.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ... Other UI stuff

        // Check if the Intent is to handle a data Uri (ACTION_VIEW).
        if (getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
            finish();
            // Clone the existing Intent with its data Uri, but change the action to ACTION_MAIN.  This is because the launcher
            // will simply bring the app to the foreground if there's an Activity with a compatible Intent in the stack.  Changing
            // to ACTION_MAIN makes it compatible.
            Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent());
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            // Restart MainActivity with the adjusted Intent, tearing down the stack if MainActivity is already present.
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            // If this Activity is not at the root, then it's Main/Other/Main, so clear this new instance off the top.
            // This can happen if initially launched via a data Uri.
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Check if the app was launched due to a data Uri. Only process the Intent once.
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            processIntent(getIntent());
        }
    }
...
```

`processIntent()` just processes the Uri returned by `intent.getData()`.

The basic technique is to detect a launch due to a data Uri, and then have `MainActivity` close and relaunch itself with an Intent that's modified.  A bit of experimentation shows that the launcher will simply bring the app to the foreground if it determines that a compatible activity is already in the stack (which is what I want).  That's why I replace the action of the intent with `Intent.ACTION_MAIN`.  I add the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in order to achieve the stack unwinding I was after.

Hope this helps someone.